# When Borel measure is equal zero on Cantor set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Assume that topological space $X$, contains subset $C$ homeomorphic to Cantor set (i.e there exists a set $C\subset X$ which is metrizable compact, without isolated points and  has closed-open basis). Assume that $\mu$ is a positive finite measure defined on  Borel subsets of $X$, which is regular and atomless. Is it then $\mu(C)=0$ ?

Thanks.

Comment: To make the question better, could you explain how you thought it up and what background material you are familiar with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily: the closed unit interval contains Cantor sets of positive Lebesgue measure. One such example is known as the [Smith-Volterra-Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) or fat Cantor set. It’s constructed in the same general way as the more familiar middle-thirds Cantor set, by removing open intervals from $[0,1]$, but the removed intervals are smaller. At stage $0$ you remove the middle $1/4$, leaving $[0,3/8]\cup[5/8,1]$. In general, at stage $n$ you have a union of $2^n$ closed intervals, and you remove the middle $2^{-2(n+1)}$ from each. An easy calculation shows that the total measure of the removed intervals is $1/2$, so the Cantor set that remains also has measure $1/2$.

Answer (score 7):

The Cantor set itself carries an atomless probability measure defined on all its Borel sets, so the answer is no.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on the answer of Carl Mummert, there is an increadibly useful theorem [due to](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm22/fm22117.pdf) Kuratowski that says the following: There exists a measurable bijection with measurable inverse between any two [Polish spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space) of the same cardinality and this cardinality is either (at most) countable or the cardinality of the continuum. It follows that, as a measurable space, the Cantor set is really the same space a $\mathbb{R}$, $[0,1]$, or $[0,1]^\infty$. So the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ corresponds to some atomless probability measure on the Cantor set. Now there is a result that says that every finite measure on the Borel sets of a metrizable metric space is automatically regular, so requiring regularity doesn't really change the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had in mind the "fair coin" measure on the Cantor space, but this achieves the same result.